# whitelisting to stop undesireable bots using IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, bots, whitelist

Basically I want to do this in IIS:

In Apache you can block many bots by simply changing your .htaccess files to OPT-IN instead of OPT-OUT, basically whitelisting instead of blacklisting. You let in Google, Yahoo, MSN, etc. and IE, Opera, Firefox, Netscape and bounce EVERYTHING else by default. The beauty here is you don't have to keep looking for bots anymore as anything that identifies itself as a bot will be bounced.

How do I achieve that in IIS? Can you please point me to an example? Thanks!

references: http://www.spanishseo.org/how-to-identify-user-agents-and-ip-addresses-for-bot-blocking

http://incredibill.blogspot.com/2011/05/whitelisting-not-blacklisting-to-stop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native way of doing this in IIS. If you're using asp.net it's easy enough to create an httpmodule to do this filtering, although unless we're talking IIS7 then only .net requests will be filtered.

Outside of that, you're looking at an IIS Filter, written in something like C++ or Delphi or something that can compile a dll. They're not easy to write either.

I wrote something similar that uses Project Honeypot (http://projecthoneypot.org/) to block spammy IP addresses. You can get it here: http://code.google.com/p/blacklistprotector/

Comment: Just a comment; it's not problematic to run .Net httpmodules on all requests in IIS6. I think the gu had a post on this... Anyway, we do it at work to enforce that users who are not logged in can not access images.

Comment: I know you can do it with wildcarding. Most articles seem to leave it to your discretion, whether to use it or not. Some say it affects performance, others say it has no effect.

Comment: I haven't noticed any effect so... xD

Comment: Thanks Simon, this will be run on IIS7, so httpmodules would work fine. :) The httpmodule you have written is a blacklist filter. Is it possible to write a whitelist filter as I described above?

Comment: I think the comment in the link you posted sums it up nicely. Whitelisting is not easy. Having set that, it would be trivial to create a httpmodule to block user-agents not on it's approved list. You'd have to get past the fact that there are a lot of valid user-agents out there.

Comment: Whitelisting also does not solve the problem. Moderately sophisticated crawlers set the user-agent to be a browser user-agent which you have to allow.